# Show that $\int_0^a \frac{\sin x}{x} dx \leq 1+\log a$ for all $a \geq 1$

Tags: analysis, inequality, definite-integrals

Show that $\int_0^a \frac{\sin x}{x} dx \leq 1+\log a$ for all $a \geq 1$.

My attempt: define $f(a)=1+\log a-\int_0^a \frac{\sin x}{x}dx$. Then the inequality is equivalent to show that $f(a) \geq 0$ for all $a \geq 1$.

$f$ is differentiable for all $a \geq 1$, since it a sum of differentiable functions (a constant, a logarithm and an integral of a continuous function that is differentiable in the interval $0 < a \leq 1$ for the fundamental theorem of calculus) in the interval $a\in[1,\infty)$.

SO it has sense to evaluate $f'$, and it is
$$f'(a)=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{\sin a}{a}=\frac{1}{a}\left(1-\sin a\right) \geq 0 \ \ \ \ \ \forall a \geq1$$
So $f$ is increasing for all $a \geq 1$, this means that if $f(1) \geq 0$ then $f(a) \geq 0$ for all $a \geq 1$ for monotonicity. It is
$$f(1)=1-\int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{x} dx$$
So it is
$$f(1) \geq 0 \iff \int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{x} dx \leq 1$$
Since $\sin t \leq t$ for all $t \geq 0$ and since $x\in[0,1]$ it is $\sin x \leq x \iff \frac{\sin x}{x} \leq 1$, so for the monotonicity of the integral it is $\int_0^1 \frac{\sin x}{x} dx \leq \int_0^1 1 dx=1$ as well; this shows that the inequality is true for all $a \geq 1$.

Is my approach correct? If there is mistakes or imprecisions let me know please.

If it is correct I would be glad to see other way to prove this. Thanks.

Comment: Your proof is neat and I don't think there is a simpler argument.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Thanks for your comment. Any other try (not necessarily simpler) is welcome!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks good to me, one other way to approach this problem is
$$ \int_0^a \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx=\int_0^1\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx+\int_1^a\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx $$
But as you said $\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx\leqslant 1$ because $\sin(x)\leqslant x$, and on the other hand
$$ \int_1^a\frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx\leqslant \int_1^a\frac{dx}{x}=\log(a)$$
Therefore $$ \int_0^a \frac{\sin(x)}{x}dx\leqslant 1+\log(a) $$

Answer (score 1):

By the self-adjointness of the Laplace transform

$$ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{1-(s\sin(a)+\cos(a))e^{-as}}{1+s^2}\,ds$$
hence by the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$$ \left|\int_{0}^{a}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right|\leq \frac{\pi}{2}+\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{ds}{e^{as}\sqrt{s^2+1}}\,ds\leq \frac{\pi}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4a}}. $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately I'm not that skilled with Laplace transform but surely I will come back to this answer when I'll become better.